# Cannont find module 'node-fetch'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I've been trying to run the code but it just shows this error i couldn't fix it because i'm not into coding that much i'm just trying to run the app

here's the error

```
Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'
    Require stack:
- c:\Users\As\Desktop\tiktok-downloader-main\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\As\Desktop\tiktok-downloader-main\index.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Comment: Have you installed the module?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a file called `package-lock.json` in the  `tiktok-downloader-main` folder. It could be in any of the sub folders. Once you find it, navigate to that folder in your terminal and run - `npm install`.

If you do not find the file called `package-lock.json`, look for `yarn.lock` file. If you find this file - in your terminal run `yarn install`.

These commands will work if you already have `npm`/`yarn` installed. For both of them, you will need `nodejs` installed.

Moreover, these commands have been tested on a Mac. Windows machine commands should be similar, but I do not gaurantee that these commands will work on windows machines as well.

Comment: it worked tysm <33